# How to prevent SignOutResult from resulting in a redirect loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm using a logoff method in my AccountController based off of the MusicStore example Microsoft provides:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        return new SignOutResult("OpenIdConnect", new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
        });
        ////_logger.LogInformation("{userName} logged out.", userName);
    }
}
```

(We're using OpenID Connect for authentication.)

This method does not sign off the user; instead, it redirects back to itself in an infinite loop.

What's the proper way in .NET Core 1.0.0 to sign off the user when using OpenID Connect?

---

**Update**:

I tried using the SignOut method below, but ended up trapped in a 302 redirect loop to 
`/Account/SignOut?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A10565%2FAccount%2FSignedOut`

---

**More info**:

Our authentication setup in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // Globally require users to be authenticated for all controller actions
        options.Filters.Add(
            new AuthorizeFilter(
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build()));
    });

...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    OpenIdConnectOptions opts = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
    {
        ClientId = Configuration["Oidc:ClientId"],
        ClientSecret = Configuration["Oidc:ClientSecret"],
        Authority = Configuration["Oidc:BaseUrl"],
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    };
    app.UseMiddleware<OktaOidcMiddleware>(Options.Create(opts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I use for Azure Active Directory OIDC sign out

```
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignedOut", "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    public async Task EndSession()
    {
        // If AAD sends a single sign-out message to the app, end the user's session, but don't redirect to AAD for sign out.
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SignedOut()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await EndSession();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This method solves one problem by signing out the user. For some reason it still redirect loops around Account/SignOut, though. Any idea what else I might need to check?

Comment: Try putting `[AllowAnonymous]` above your Index method in your Home controller and see what that does. Also, for this to work, you will need a view called SignedOut.cshtml . You can just replace the return View() with return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't even make it that far; it just stays looped in SignOut. I think the RedirectUri parameter is not acting as it should.

Comment: It never hits the SignedOut method?

Comment: `public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignedOut", "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
            var signOut = SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return signOut;
        }`

Comment: Copy and paste my comment above so you can put a break on the return of SignOut. That could be the insight you need.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, so I ended up adding a redirect after the `SignOut` call for now. Curious that it's not redirecting properly...

Comment: I just realized... instead of returning a new sign out result try return signout

Comment: As in the `return SignOut` you're using, correct? I tried using your code and it does log out, but I still had to manually add the redirect afterwards for some reason.

Comment: How is your OAuth setup in Startup.cs

Comment: Good question -- added some more context to my question.

Comment: Ok instead of `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());` try `app.UseCookieAuthentication();`

Comment: Also add app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()

Comment: Neither of those changes affect the redirect loop -- I still end up having to return a separate redirect.

Comment: @Chris: did you ever get this sorted out? I believe your global filter might be disallowing the use of the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.